Python multiprocessing with multiple locks slower than single lock
I am making experiments with multiprocessing in Python. I wrote some code that requires concurrent modification of 3 different variables (a dict, a float and an int), shared across the different process. My understanding of the works behind locking tells me that if I have 3 different shared variables, it will be more efficient to assign a lock to each one. After all, why should process 2 wait to modify variable A just because process 1 is modifying variable B? It makes sense to me that if you need to lock variable B, then A should still be accessible to other processes.
I run the 2 toy examples below, based on a real program I'm writing, and to my surprise the code runs faster with a single lock!
Single lock: 2.1 seconds
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

class ToyClass:
    def __init__(self, shared_a, shared_b):
        self.a = shared_a
        self.b = shared_b

    def update_a(self, key, n, lock):
        with lock:
            if key not in self.a:
                self.a[key] = np.zeros(4)
            self.a[key][n] += 1

    def update_b(self, lock):
        with lock:
            self.b.value = max(0.1, self.b.value - 0.01)

def run_episode(toy, counter, lock):
    key = np.random.randint(100)
    n = np.random.randint(4)
    toy.update_a(key, n, lock)
    toy.update_b(lock)
    with lock:
        counter.value += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_episodes = 1000
    num_processes = 4

    t0 = time.time()

    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        shared_a = manager.dict()
        shared_b = manager.Value('d', 0)
        counter = manager.Value('i', 0)

        toy = ToyClass(shared_a=shared_a, shared_b=shared_b)

        # Single lock
        lock = manager.Lock()

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_processes)

        for _ in range(num_episodes):
            pool.apply_async(run_episode, args=(toy, counter, lock))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    tf = time.time()

    print(f"Time to compute single lock: {tf - t0} seconds")

Multiple locks: 2.85 seconds!!
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time


class ToyClass:  ## Same definition as for single lock
    def __init__(self, shared_a, shared_b):
        self.a = shared_a
        self.b = shared_b

    def update_a(self, key, n, lock):
        with lock:
            if key not in self.a:
                self.a[key] = np.zeros(4)
            self.a[key][n] += 1 

    def update_b(self, lock):
        with lock:
            self.b.value = max(0.1, self.b.value - 0.01)

def run_episode(toy, counter, lock_a, lock_b, lock_count):
    key = np.random.randint(100)
    n = np.random.randint(4)
    toy.update_a(key, n, lock_a)
    toy.update_b(lock_b)
    with lock_count:
        counter.value += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_episodes = 1000
    num_processes = 4

    t0 = time.time()

    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        shared_a = manager.dict()
        shared_b = manager.Value('d', 0)
        counter = manager.Value('i', 0)

        toy = ToyClass(shared_a=shared_a, shared_b=shared_b)

        # 3 locks for 3 shared variables
        lock_a = manager.Lock()
        lock_b = manager.Lock()
        lock_count = manager.Lock()

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_processes)

        for _ in range(num_episodes):
            pool.apply_async(run_episode, args=(toy, counter, lock_a, lock_b, lock_count))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    tf = time.time()

    print(f"Time to compute multi-lock: {tf - t0} seconds")

What am I missing here? Is there a computational overhead when switching between locks that outweighs any potential benefit? These are just flags, how can it be?
Note: I know the code runs much faster when single process/thread, but this is part of an experiment precisely to understand the downsides of multiprocessing.

fyi, update_a is bugged, and doesn't do what you expect. a[key] = somthing is valid, but a[key][n] = something is not valid and does nothing because a[key][n] is a copy

you will have to do something like temp = a[key]; temp[n] = something; a[key] = temp

also you should consider using a defaultdict instead of dict, because the check-then-initialize-if-not-initialized is super slow, it is the equivalent of going to the supermarket just to check if they have milk then coming back home to grab the money to then go back and buy the milk

This has nothing to do with the locking, you are just sending 3 locks per call instead of 1, which is 3 times the transmission overhead.
to verify this you can test

keep sending the 3 locks but only use 1 of them, you will get the same time as using the 3 locks
change 2 of the locks to be simple Manager.Value objects, still the same time as 3 locks.

the locking part plays no role in this, you are just sending the locks over and over, which you can avoid by using an initializer when spawning the pool.
lock_a = None
lock_b = None
lock_counter = None
def initialize_locks(val1,val2,val3):
    global lock_a, lock_b, lock_counter
    lock_a = val1
    lock_b = val2
    lock_counter = val3

...

pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_processes, initializer=initialize_locks, initargs=(lock_a, lock_b, lock_counter,))

Also if you are using the initializer you should instead use multiprocessing.Lock instead, as it is faster than Manager.Lock, same applied to Multiprocessing.Value instead of Manager.Value

Thank you Ahmed! I have been playing around with different combinations, and made the following findings:
The fastest execution is achieved indeed when shared variables are created from multiprocessing instead of manager (the dict needs to be created from manager though).
But I also found 2 very interesting results:

The initialization is not required. It does not affect the speed and the code seems to run. Maybe I'm missing something?
The optimal speed is achieved when lock_a and lock_b are defined from mp, but lock_counter is defined from manager! What is going on?


@Leo the initialization is required on windows and mac, you can skip it on linux due to fork, the important part is that the arguments of apply_async should contain only the changing data. as for the point of using mp.Lock vs manager.Lock, the measurements from this benchmark are all within the margin of error, so i don't think it is suitable for comparing those primitives, the mp.Lock one is a mutex in shared memory while the manager.Lock one is waiting on a socket for the manager to send you the "go", the mp.Lock one is therefore faster, but this benchmark doesn't make this clear.
